# Δ-Interpolation doesn't imply Beth property in abstract model theory: a simple counterexample?

Tags: logic, model-theory

It's known that for an abstract logic $\mathcal{L}$ (for definitions cfr. Barwise J. & Feferman S. (eds.), [*Model-Theoretic Logics*](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Model-Theoretic-Logics/toc/pl/1235417263), Springer-Verlag, 1985) having Δ-Interpolation (also called Suslin-Kleene property) doesn't imply having Beth property. The only counterexample I've found is the logic $\Delta(\mathcal{L}_Q)$, the $\Delta$-closure of $\mathcal{L}_Q$ (first-order logic plus the quantifier 'there exist uncountably many'), which by definition of $\Delta$-closure operation has $\Delta$-interpolation, but it doesn't have Beth. The problem is that the only proof I know of is from Shelah's [*The theorems of Beth and Craig in abstract model theory, III: $\Delta$-logics and infinitary logics*](https://shelah.logic.at/files/197887/113.pdf) (Israel Journal of Mathematics 69/2, 1990), but it's a very general and complex one and the counterexample I'm interested in is only a simple corollary of it. Does a simpler and more specific/direct proof producing a counterexample only to the implication above exist?

Comment: What is Δ-interpolation? What is Beth's property?

Comment: For the definitions check the link to Barwise&Feferman's textbook (it's open access); in particular: abstract logic is defined in Definition II.1.1.1 (page 27); Beth property in Definition II.1.2.4.(ix) (page 32); $\Delta$-interpolation in II.7.2.1 (page 70); $\Delta$-closure in II.7.2.3 (page 71).